# passing self from Objective C to C++, no more deallocation

Tags: c++, objective-c, memory-management, self

I hope someone can help me with my problem, searched long and didn't find a sufficent answer.

I'm using Objective-C++ to merge Objective C and C++ classes (since for my project i need to inherit classes from both languages). My main class is a Objective-C class and I have a small helper class in C++, which gets passed in the Objective-C object and calls functions of it.

My problem is that while this works, there is no deallocation (or deconstruction) happening. It seems that passing self in the Objective-C class init method to the C++ class creates some sort of memory lock or leak when I try to save the Objective-C object to a class variable in the C++ object.

I am using ARC.

Here is the sample code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyObjCClass : NSObject
@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    MyObjCClass *test = [[MyObjCClass alloc] init];
    test = nil;
}

class MyCppClass {
public:
    MyCppClass(void *test);
    ~MyCppClass();

private:
    void testFunction();
    MyObjCClass *myObjCObject;

};


MyCppClass::MyCppClass(void *test){
    MyObjCClass *obj = (__bridge MyObjCClass *) test;
    myObjCObject = obj; //when doing this, there is no more deallocation/deconstruction called
    NSLog(@"constructing c++ class");
}

MyCppClass::~MyCppClass(){
    NSLog(@"deconstructing c++ class");
}

@implementation MyObjCClass {
    MyCppClass *myCppObject;
}

- (instancetype)init
{
    if (self) {
        NSLog(@"initializing ObjC class");
        myCppObject = new MyCppClass((__bridge void *) self);
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    delete myCppObject;
    NSLog(@"deallocating ObjC class");
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
MyCppClass::MyCppClass(void *test){
    MyObjCClass *obj = (__bridge MyObjCClass *) test;
    myObjCObject = obj; // <-- Creates a strong reference
    NSLog(@"constructing c++ class");
}
```

a strong reference to the object is created, and that prevents the
object from being deallocated. A possible solution is to use
a weak reference instead:

```
class MyCppClass {
// ...        

private:
    void testFunction();
    __weak MyObjCClass *myObjCObject; // <-- Weak reference

};
```

The weak pointer is set to `nil` when the object is deallocated.

For more information, see [Use Weak References to Avoid Retain Cycles](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-1000810) in the "Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide".